# get highest and sum of values from two table

Tags: php, mysql

I Want to show accounts with their highest rank characters and SUM of Their Time Where stats on table accounts is `1` with just in one Query.

I have Two Table with below data :

***Table: Accounts:***

```
Id| Username |Stats
1 | player1  |1
2 | goodman  |1
3 | goodbat  |1
4 | ashasdd  |0
```

***Table: Characters:***

```
Guid| Account | Name | Rank | Time |
213 |    1    | fres |  2   |  51  |
214 |    2    | sdg2 |  3   |  12  |
215 |    2    | fgax |  4   |  99  |
216 |    3    | zFvx |  8   |  23  |
217 |    3    | Sgzs |  2   |  13  |
```

**Output/Result:** (Show Accounts characters with their Highest rank character and Their Sum of time)

```
Username : player1 | Name: fres(Rank:2) |Time : 51
Username : goodman | Name: fgax(Rank:4) |Time : 111
Username : goodbat | Name: zFvx(Rank:8) |Time : 36
```

what's the simple MySQL Query ?

***My bad Query:*** (don't work)

```
SELECT a.username, a.email, c.name, SUM(c.time), c.rank
FROM `auth`.`account` a, `characters`.`characters` c
WHERE a.id=c.account
ORDER BY c.rank ASC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: What value are you expecting in the result for `rank`?  It's ambiguous since you have multiple ranks per account ID in the characters table.  Please include your desired output in the question.

Comment: Result must return with highest rank of each account character.

Comment: +root in the future provide structure and demo data on a service like gist.github or pastebin, this helps people when they have something to test the query against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be enough.. i think.

```
SELECT c.Account, a.Username, c.Name, MAX(c.Rank) as maxrank, SUM(c.TIME) as sumtime  FROM characters c LEFT JOIN Accounts a ON a.Id=c.Account GROUP By c.Account;
```

Comment: How do you know account is id??

Comment: you down vote me cause you cant read... wow... nice community

Comment: yeah and i can read an TABLE account has an ID, when he has an INT column in a second table with name Account i add 1+1 and may think this is his FK. if there really is a constrain on it and/or a key is outside the scope of the question. so and with this. i wasted enough time on you.

Comment: Order was left `SELECT c.Account, a.Username, c.Name, MAX(c.level) AS maxrank, SUM(c.totalTIME) AS sumtime  FROM characters.characters c LEFT JOIN auth.Account a ON a.Id=c.Account GROUP BY c.Account ORDER BY maxrank DESC;`.

Comment: ignorance is bliss I guess...it is not outside the scope when he asked how to join it AND LEFT OUT THE ON CLAUSE, now he edits it so i look like im blind huh ???? If you were a mind reader, why didn't you just say so?

Comment: @Hituptony Why will damage your nerves? You may grow old, thanks all ;)

Comment: +hituptony wtf.. i left out the order not the on clouse... whats wrong with you? see the history of my post. (oh wait i dont have one since i not edited it... bummer)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work

```
SELECT username, name, d.rank, c.Time
FROM (

    SELECT a.Username, b.account, MAX( b.Rank ) AS rank, SUM( b.Time ) AS TIME
    FROM accounts a
    INNER JOIN characters b ON a.ID = b.Account
    WHERE a.stats =1
    GROUP BY a.Username
) AS c
JOIN characters d ON d.account = c.account
AND d.rank = c.rank
ORDER BY rank
```

Not sure how to do it in just one select tho since then you might get the wrong name, thats not registered with the max rank.